# PHP display image from Database(medium blob)

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I currently have a database where i can store images in..
But the PHP page i created to display them... doesnt work.
But when i use the link as scr for a < img> it shows a empty image frame.
if i echo the image directly, i get a lot of strange signs

the way i want to display the images is:
    < img src="image.php?image="'.$imageID.'/>

the code i use for displaying the image(image.php) is:

```
 <?php session_start();
 if(!isset($_GET['image']))
 {
     header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 }
 else{
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', '45345345435435345', 'wewfsersdfds');
            if (!$link) {
                echo "error";
                die;
            }

            $db_selected = mysql_select_db(Tha base, $link);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                echo "error";
                die;
            }
 $nummer=(int)trim(stripslashes($_GET['image']));
 $mynr=$nummer;
 $sql="SELECT * FROM Foto WHERE fotonr=$mynr";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 if(!$result)
 {
     echo "error".mysql_error();
     header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 }
 else
 {

     $foto = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

     header("Content-type: ".$foto['type']);
     echo $foto['image'];


 }
 }
 ?>
```

I tried a lot already but it wont work :(
i updated the code to the newest version.
Made mistakes with the sql(selected nothing/never do mysql_real_escape_string of a int)

Now it shows a straight line of characters, instead of an image, thats at least a improvement...

Can someone help me?

Thanx for your time!

Comment: why are you storing images inside of a database? wouldn't it make more sense to store the file in your file system, and a reference to that file's path in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I know it can be tricky. I think it has to do with how your storing it, not how your outputting it. I have one example of storage from a recent project I can show.

```
$fp = fopen($image_path, 'r');
$image = fread($fp, filesize($image_path));
$image = addslashes($image);
fclose($fp);

// save $image into DB.
```

Not sure if you do similar with file_get_contents. How I output is similar to how you are doing it, only I use a ORM and a framework.

Comment: current code im  using is from someone else, its                           $content = file_get_contents($tmpName); 
     $data = unpack("H*hex", $content ); 
     $mycontent = '0x'.$data['hex'];                                                                and it works, and the size is good...

Comment: I've never seen it done that way before. Try using my method and then saving the problematic image and trying to view it.

Comment: What i get back is http://www.nac-verkeerscholen.nl/test/image.php?image=9 dont know if its right or wrong... but its diffrent from the initial image...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your problem is in your conversion - perhaps between strings and images, or perhaps between the different image formats.

Have you tried saving the image gotten through image.php, and comparing the binary against the known-good image file?  Perhaps once you do that, the answer will be apparent (e.g. wrong length, corrupted header, etc.)

You may want to consider a different database record.  Most db's support storage of binary blob data, which you could more simply return.  This would be simpler (and take less space in your db!) than using the php functions to stringify and imagecreatefromstring.

Also, I believe that you're attempting to use imagegif, imagejpeg, imaging to perform image format conversion for you.  This isn't how I understand them to work, based on my reading at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php. Try storing and retrieving the same format to tease out whether this is your problem.

Try looking at Content-type. I think it's case sensitive.  Try Content-Type.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: well the string i get back now, is of the right size, but if i try to paste it into a txt, and chaning txt to the image format it was... it wont work. You say "support storage of binary blob", do you mean blob(too small) or the binary datatype. And there is no imageconversion, multiple forms of images are stored in the database(allong with their imagetype) just trying to display something...    thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Using some MySQL tool, can you pull an image string down and compare it against your retrieved string? Are they the same?  Can you give an example of the content type you're using?

Comment: Well i pulled the string down... and its diffrent from what the image looks like when i open it. As the image has a lot of unkown characters, and the image from the db has all known characters... its this the diffrence between ANSI or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Foto WHERE fotonr=$mynr";
        $result = $conn -> query($sql);
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $img= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(                        $row['image'] ).'"  width=350px0px height=300px/>';
}
echo $img;
```